# Moving database from PMA to Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, phpmyadmin

I have an existing MySQL database that I set up on PMA, it has FKs that references columns that are not primary keys. Now I am trying to move the database to Django and am having trouble because when I try to set up d Foreign Keys in django it automatically references the Primary Key of the table that I am attempting to reference so the data doesnt match because column A and column B do not contain the same info. Is there a way to tell django what column to reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `to_field` attribute of a ForeignKey.

Django should detect this automatically if you use `./manage.py inspectdb`, though.